# SQL Server Logs consistently get filled

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, transaction-log, maintenance-plan

I have issues with transaction logs on SQL Server 2012. I set up a job that does an automatic cleanup of logs, I used the following the plans below.

**Job name: Cleanup DB Logs**

**Step 1: Do transaction log backup using Management wizard & go to 
"Step 2"**

```
GO
BACKUP LOG [XXXX_Database] TO  DISK = N'I:\XXX_Database.Trn' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'XXX_Database-Transaction Log  Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

**Step 2: Perform shrink log & transaction log backup and exit upon success e.g. here is the step 2 script below:**

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'CAR2_Analysis_Database_log' , 20)
GO
BACKUP LOG [XXXX_Database] TO  DISK = N'I:\XXX_Database.Trn' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'XXX_Database-Transaction Log  Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'XXX_Database_log' , 20)
GO
```

Then I schedule the job to run every 3 hours daily. The idea of the above script is to force truncation. It works fine, however, after 2 days I see that the STEP 2 disappears from the Job. My question why does this happen? Any pointer would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is your DBA removing it in anger at you doing such a thing?

Comment: No the DBA is not removing it. I already checked. DBA is not sure why it is removed too.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by doing this? 
are you actually using transaction log backups as part of your DR setup? constantly shrinking the file is a bad idea, as then it'll just have to grow again.
if you're simply trying to avoid the pain of a growing transaction log that you don't care about, put your database into "Simple" recovery model.